# Convert an input result/string to integer in Python

Tags: python, string, integer

I am having issue with running this code. When I try to run it, it says it won't work because age is a string. How do I convert the string to an integer? I have also tried to do 18 - int(age) and that won't work either.

```
    age = input ("How old are you? (): ")
    if int(age) > 18 :
        print("You're old enough to drink") 
    else:
        print("You're not old enough to drink. Wait", + 18 - age, "more years")
```

Comment: Can you share with us the output this code produces and the output you expected it to produces.

Comment: Where you do `if int(age) > 18`, in your own words: a) what does the `int(age)` part mean? b) do you expect this to modify `age`? Why or why not?

Comment: "I have also tried to do 18 - int(age) and that won't work either." What do you mean, "won't work"? How exactly did you "try" this; what happened when you tried; and how is that different from what is supposed to happen?

Comment: may be you are entering strings like "19.0" ....you can't directly convert str to int if str has a float in str format .... you can use float for this... float(age)

Answer (score 1):

```
age = input("How old are you? (): "))
try:
    age = int(age)
    if age > 18 :
        print("You're old enough to drink.") 
    else:
        print(f"You're not old enough to drink. Wait {18-age} more years.")
except:
    print("You did not enter a valid age.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that `input("How old are you? (): ")` is `int(input("How old are you? (): "))`

```py
age = int(input("How old are you? (): "))
if int(age) > 18 :
    print("You're old enough to drink") 
else:
    print("You're not old enough to drink. Wait {} more years".format(18-age))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add [`try.. except..`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)

Like this:

```
age = input("How old are you? (): "))
try:
    age = int(age)
    if age > 18 :
        print("You're old enough to drink.") 
    else:
        print(f"You're not old enough to drink. Wait {18-age} more years.")
except ValueError:
    print("Not a valid age. Please enter again")
```

and by the way, you can use `f'` strings for string format.

or use `.format` :

```
print("You're not old enough to drink. Wait {0} more years.".format(18-age))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    age = input ("How old are you?  ")
#Check if the input is a positive integer
    if age.isdigit() >0:
        break
if int(age) > 18 :
    print("You're old enough to drink.") 
else:
    print("You're not old enough to drink. Wait",18 - int(age), "more years.")
#Remove the + in 18 because you already use comma after'Wait'
```

Comment: I use while loop to repeat the prompt for invalid input.